# Can I append div on button click in react?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I am trying to make a simple hotel reservation web app in react. Here is what I want to achieve. A user selects `room`, `adults`, and `children` in number and reserve he's/her own hotels. The following screenshot depicts exactly what I want to do.

[image: I wanted this design]

As you see from the above screenshot, when I click `children's` Increment `+` button, I wanted to append a div having `children` and their age. In the above screenshot, as I Incremented children value `2` times  Two divs with children and their age has been appended.

I already design the component as follows. I want the logic here to apply.
[image: here is what I design]

Here is my Component code, I use `tailwindcss` for styling

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import rateIcon from "../../../assets/rate-cons.PNG";
import {
  CheckIcon,
  InformationCircleIcon,
  WifiIcon,
  ParkingIcon,
  HeartIcon,
  SwitchVerticalIcon,
  AdjustmentsIcon,
  MapIcon,
  MinusIcon,
  PlusIcon,
} from "@heroicons/react/outline";
import mapImage from "../../../assets/map.PNG";
import { LocationMarkerIcon } from "@heroicons/react/solid";
import DatePickers from "../DatePicker/DatePicker";
import {
  HotelOutlined,
  PeopleAltOutlined,
  RoomOutlined,
  RoomService,
} from "@material-ui/icons";
import {
  ChildFriendly,
  FamilyRestroomOutlined,
  FamilyRestroomRounded,
} from "@mui/icons-material";
const Hero = () => {
  const [rooms, setRooms] = useState(0);
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const showGuestInfo = () => setShow(!show);

  const addRooms = () => {
    setRooms(rooms + 1);
  };
  const removeRooms = () => {
    if (rooms > 1) {
      setRooms(rooms - 1);
    } else {
      setRooms(rooms);
    }
  };
  return ( 

    <div className="p-3  flex w-full  flex flex-col relative">
                    <div className="flex flex-col border-b border-gray">
                      <div className="p-2 flex justify-between items-center ">
                        <div className="flex text-sm items-center space-x-2">
                          <HotelOutlined />
                          <p>Rooms</p>
                        </div>
                        <div className="flex space-x-4 border p-2">
                          <p>
                            <MinusIcon
                              // onClick={removeRooms}
                              className="bg-gray-light h-6 cursor-pointer"
                            />
                          </p>
                          <p>{rooms}</p>
                          <PlusIcon
                            // onClick={addRooms}
                            className=" bg-gray-light h-6 cursor-pointer"
                          />
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div className="p-2 flex justify-between items-center">
                        <div className="flex text-sm items-center space-x-2">
                          <PeopleAltOutlined />
                          <p>Adults</p>
                        </div>
                        <div className="flex space-x-4 border p-2">
                          <p>
                            <MinusIcon
                              // onClick={removeRooms}
                              className="h-6 bg-gray-light cursor-pointer"
                            />
                          </p>
                          <p>{rooms}</p>
                          <PlusIcon
                            // onClick={addRooms}
                            className="h-6 bg-gray-light cursor-pointer"
                          />
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div className="p-2 flex justify-between items-center">
                        <div className="flex text-sm items-center space-x-2">
                          <FamilyRestroomOutlined />
                          <p>Childrens</p>
                        </div>
                        <div className="flex space-x-4 border p-2">
                          <p>
                            <MinusIcon
                              onClick={removeRooms}
                              className="h-6 bg-gray-light cursor-pointer"
                            />
                          </p>
                          <p>{rooms}</p>
                          <PlusIcon
                            onClick={addRooms}
                            className="h-6 bg-gray-light cursor-pointer"
                          />
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="border-t p-2 border-gray ">
                      <button className="p-2 border-t border-gray  bg-black w-full text-white">
                        Update
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
 );
};
```

**How can I build this logic?**

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to do this in React is to set the state of your component (or its parent). Then when you render the component, you use the state to decide what to render. So you don't "append" a div as much as you decide that you need a div at a certain spot due to the state.

In this case, you might have a list of children's ages as state. Clicking on the + button will add an element to this list, probably defaulting to 0. Then for each child's age, you render a `<div>` and a `<select>` with that age. If the age is 0, then you have a message telling the user to select an age. When the user selects an age, you update the list at the correct position with that age.

Note that this can be implemented as a separate component to simplify the code in the top-level view.

The key thing here is that you never manipulate the DOM directly like you would with pure JavaScript or JQuery. Instead, you keep some data and use it to decide what to render.

Comment: Can you give me this logic with a code? Thanks

Comment: @TeshAych You already do this with rooms. You can do something similar, but a bit more complex, with children. I suggest you find more tutorials to help you understand the concepts I describe here.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't have example, here is a [repro on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-functional-boilerplate-16-13-1-deosfo) on how you can do it, and here is the code :

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

const App = () => {
  const [children, setChildren] = React.useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      Children :{' '}
      <input
        type="number"
        value={children}
        onChange={(e) => setChildren(Number(e.target.value))}
      />
      {Array.from(Array(Number(children)).keys()).map((child, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
          child of <input type="number" /> years old
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

The state `children` store the number of children. We then just render as many div as this number by creating an array and mapping over it with this particular line :

```
Array.from(Array(Number(children)).keys())
```